# Not getting specific data from detail table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

Here is Named query to fetch specific track with specific user metadata.

```
"SELECT t FROM Track t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.metadata tm WHERE t.id= :id AND tm.userID = :userID"
```

In Track entity i am having metadata list with @OneToMany relationship with join table inbetween name = tracks_metadata_join.

```
//TrackMetadata


 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=TrackMetadata.class, orphanRemoval = true) 

 @JoinTable(name = "tracks_metadata_join", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "track_id", 

 referencedColumnName = "id", table = "tracks") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( 

 name = "track_metadata_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "tracks_metadata")) 

 @JsonProperty 

 private List<TrackMetadata> metadata = new ArrayList<>();
```

The result of above query is Track with all it's all metadata, But i want Track with particular metadata. like user specific. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you read `Track` and initialize its `metadata` collection, Hibernate will populate the entire collection. That's how Hibernate works.

If you want only specific `metadata` elements loaded, then you could make the association bidirectional and load the desired metadata only:

```
select tm from TrackMetaData tm where tm.track.id = :id and tm.userID = :userID
```

Comment: Hi, does it goes in subquery or in metadata class? I mean where do i write this query ?

Comment: You write it instead of your original query.

Comment: It's not working, Getting mapping errors because TrackMetadata is child table of Track. We can't query it inside Track entity.

Comment: Did you make the association bidirectional?

Comment: Yeah, i made it bidirectional first then tried above query.

Comment: Mind showing the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103009/discussion-between-bipin-vayalu-and-dragan-bozanovic).

Comment: {select tm from TrackMetaData tm where tm.track.id = :id and tm.userID = :userID} This query give error about mapping. I double checked mapping all looks good.

Comment: i think here is right conclusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102152/hibernate-criteria-api-filtering-collection-property

Comment: Why do you not want to post the error you get? It is impossible to tell what's wrong if we don't know it. There are thousands of possible 'errors about mapping'. :)

Comment: I managed this using hibernate filters.